# Simple plugin for showing RSS subscription links?

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation, rss

Does someone know of a simple plugin for showing RSS feeds? I need something dead simple that only show the links and would rather re-use something before rolling one myself.

Comment: What exactly you are trying to do? Show links to feed? On page or self-discovery links (those browsers detect in put in address bar)?

Comment: Show links to feed. Just a simple plugin with a widget that does bloginfo('atom_url'); with a nice RSS icon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a plugin for this, [RSS Icon Widget](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/rss-icon-widget/). However it looks like it hasn't been tested on any version past 2.8. It looks fairly simple, so it could still work.

Otherwise the easiest way to accomplish this is to just create a new text widget and write the HTML to display any icon you'd like and link it to your feed. A plugin may even be overkill for this. I believe this is normally something that is built into your theme.